# Google Map v3 asp.net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

Controller:

```
public ActionResult FeaturedDealers()
{
   var featuredDealers = dealerRepository.GetFeaturedDealers().ToList();
      return View(featuredDealers);
}
```

View

```
var locations = [
    <% foreach (var dealer in Model) { %>
    ['<%: dealer.Website %>', <%: String.Format("{0:F}", dealer.Latitude) %>, <%: String.Format("{0:F}", dealer.Longitude) %>],
    <% } %>];
```

I'm trying to create a basic dealer locator using Google Maps.
I'm having issues with multiple markers.
The above works, but I know that it is wrong.
Help is much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var locations = <%= Json.Encode(Model.Select(x => new[] { 
    x.Website, 
    String.Format("{0:F}", x.Latitude), 
    String.Format("{0:F}", x.Longitude)  
})) %>;
```

Obviously it would be a crime to put this Select statement in a view, thus prepare your model appropriately in the controller before handling it to the view, like this:

```
public ActionResult FeaturedDealers()
{
    var featuredDealers = dealerRepository
        .GetFeaturedDealers()
        .Select(x => new[] 
        {
            x.Website, 
            String.Format("{0:F}", x.Latitude), 
            String.Format("{0:F}", x.Longitude)  
        });
    return View(featuredDealers);
}
```

and then:

```
var locations = <%= Json.Encode(Model) %>;
```